# Is it possible to open a Visual Studio Model (modelproj) in a version of visual studio 2015 other than Ultimate/Enterprise?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uml

The microsoft documentation on MSDN [Read models and diagrams in other Visual Studio editions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997431.aspx) states this is possible

> When you open a model in a version of Visual Studio that does not
>   support model creation, the model opens in read-only mode. In this
>   mode, you can change the layout of the diagrams, but you cannot change
>   the model.[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997431.aspx)

When I open a solution that contains a model project in Visual Studio 2015 professional I get an "Unsupported Project Dialogue". The file extension modelproj is also not recognised when I attempt to  File -> Open Project.

Comment: Did you get to resolve this issue?

Comment: @CarlosJimenezBermudez No, but if you do please post an answer here.